# Runtime error 91 in Excel/VBA on assigning Workbook variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code in `Creator workbook` and I am copying data from the data file I select. But the code gives me the following error:

> Object variable or with block variable not set

```
Sub transfer()
Dim myfile As Workbook
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Dim DataWs As Worksheet

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

myfile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse For Data file")
Workbooks.Open myfile
Set DataWs = myfile.Sheets("Instru Input")

myWs.Range("C3:C11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("E3:E11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("G3:G11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("I3:I11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("H2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("K3:K11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("I2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("M3:M11000").Copy
DataWs.Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
myWs.Range("O3:O11000").Copy


ThisWorkbook.SaveAs

ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer, but a general comment/query: If you're doing `Range1.Copy` immediately followed by `Range2.PasteSpecial  xlPasteAll`, why not just do it all in 1 line without the clipboard as `Range1.Copy Destination:=Range2`?

Comment: In genreal, try to avoid selecting and activating anything in Excel with VBA - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: @Chronocidal its a nice suggestion but i am new to vba so i really dont know how to get that ... if you could elaborate it for me ..that would be great

Comment: @Chronocidal - good idea indeed, it could be even shorter, omitting the named parameter.

Comment: @j.doe For example, `myWs.Range("C3:C11000").Copy` and `DataWs.Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` can be combined in 1 line: `myWs.Range("C3:C11000").Copy Destination:=DataWs.Range("E2")` - it also makes it slightly easier to read when debugging, because you can see it just says "copy this data to this location"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what `GetOpenFileName` does by the specification [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.getopenfilename):

> Displays the standard Open dialog box and gets a file name from the user without actually opening any files.

Thus, once you get the file name (with the file path) as a string, it should be recorded as a string. Using this string, a workbook variable could be assigned with `Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse For Data file")
    Debug.Print fileName

    Dim myWb As Workbook
    Set myWb = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

End Sub
```

In general, this is how a working code, taking some info from one worksheet to a worksheet in another workbook would look like:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse For Data file")
    Debug.Print fileName

    Dim targetWs As Worksheet
    Set targetWs = Workbooks.Open(fileName).Worksheets("Instru Input")

    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
    'To avoid using the ActiveSheet:
    Set sourceWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NameOfTheWorksheet") 

    With sourceWs
        .Range("C3:C11000").Copy targetWs.Range("E2")
        .Range("E3:E11000").Copy targetWs.Range("F2")
        'And so on ...
    End With

    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "WriteFileAddressHere.xlsb"
    ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Make sure that you change "NameOfTheWorksheet" string and "WriteFileAddressHere.xlsb" to something relevant.

Comment: so what change should i make to the above code? to get that functionality of choosing the file and then copying  data from that workbook?

Comment: worked with some changes but my error got solved an now i am getting the expected output ...thanks alot!

Comment: question...how do i close the selected workbook after copying? @Vityata

Comment: @j.doe - write - `targetWs.Parent.Close True` or better declare the other workbook as a variable and close it this way.

Comment: didnt get you ... will this come in the end of the code?

Comment: @j.doe - write it instead of `ThisWorkbook.Close`. But, the better option is probably to refactor, declare the other workbook as a variable and close it.